# A newbie text for learning the independence of CH

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

As a newbie, I'm trying to learn a (rigorous) proof of the independence of CH, but I'm struggling a bit with my current text.  I really like the approach and style of
[*An Introduction To Set Theory*, W.A.R. Weiss, 2014](http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/Set_Theory.pdf), but I can't see it clearly indicated that this PDF covers the theorems of the independence of CH.

If I work my way through this PDF, will I see the forcing proof (originally by Cohen) that the negation of CH is consistent?

Answer (score 8):

What an odd question. I'm not familiar with the book, but I was able to ascertain quickly that the answer is no.

Searching the pdf for the words "force" or "forcing" gives no results. Searching for "Cohen" gives two results, which allude to Cohen's proof but do not indicate it will be covered in the current book. The table of contents indicates nothing about the independence of $\mathsf{CH}$ (and this topic would certainly require its own chapter!). So no, it's safe to say you won't learn Cohen's forcing proof from this book.

What you will learn, in Chapter 13, is Gödel's theorem that $\mathsf{GCH}$ is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ - that is, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ does not prove the negation of the (generalized) continuum hypothesis. This is one half of the theorem that $\mathsf{(G)CH}$ is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. The other half is Cohen's proof that the negation of $\mathsf{(G)CH}$ is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$.